# Prove that $S$ is an integral domain and $T$ is not an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

Let

- $R = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$
- $R^i \subset R$ be the abelian subgroup of $R$ generated by elements of $\mathbb{C}$ times monomials of degree at least $i$
- $I = (x^3+x^2-y^2)$
- $S = R/I$
- $S^i$ be the group generated by the image of $R^i$ in $S$

Consider the product on $S^i/S^{i+1} \times S^j/S^{j+1}$ given by 
$$
(a + S^{i+1})(b+S^{j+1}) = ab + S^{i+j+1} \in S^{i+j}/S^{i+j+1}.
$$
Let

- $T = \oplus_{i= 0}^{\infty} S^i/S^{i+1}$. The operation above makes $T$ into a ring.

Prove that

1. $S$ is an integral domain.
2. $T$ is not an integral domain.

Edit (What I did):
For part 1, I tried showing that $I$ is a prime ideal but didn't get far.
For part 2, I tried generalizing something of the form
$$
(a,0,0,...)(0,b,0,0,...) = (0,0,0,...)
$$ where $a \neq 0 $ and $b \neq 0$.

Comment: your try???????

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth I don't understand what you mean by "your try".

Comment: @ He means, what did you try? It is usually good practise to say what you have attempted and how you are confused.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth See edit

Comment: @algor207 The multiplication is not defined to be component-wise.

Comment: @Saurabh Yes, you're right, Guess Ill have to try a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

$f=y^2-x^2(x+1)$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb C[x,y]$. This can be proved elementary by supposing that $f$ is a product of two polynomials necessarily of degree one in $y$ and getting a contradiction, or one can use the Eisenstein's criterion for the prime element $x+1$. To conclude, $S$ is indeed an integral domain.

$T$ instead is not an integral domain since $x^2=y^2$ in $T$, so $(x-y)(x+y)=0$, and $x\ne\pm y$.

Comment: In a rather boring way you have described $T$ as being the associated graded ring of $S$ at its maximal ideal. The spectrum of $T$ is the tangent space of the nodal cubic at the origin and $T\simeq\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2-x^2)$.

Comment: Could you elaborate why $T\simeq\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2-x^2)$?

Comment: Do you have the book of Bruns and Herzog?

Comment: Yes, the book "Cohen-Macaulay rings". Why?

Comment: Then read at page 189 how look the associated graded ring in this case.

Comment: Are you talking about Lemma 4.6.5 or Proposition 4.6.6 on page 189. I don't see the connection.

Comment: I'm talking about the first 12 lines on page 189. (Recall what I said: "T as being the *associated graded ring* of S at its maximal ideal.")